# Variable loses scope when used through button.click handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scope

When I call my function at `Me.Load` everything is OK, but when I trigger my function only on the button click event all variables inside lose their set values.  I just started on VB.NET so I don't fully understand scope nature here.

**Here is my code:**

```
Public Class WorkflowForward
    Inherits FileBound.Web.FBBasePage

    ' Private decalrations
    Private cfile_id As String = ""                             ' Current files ID
    Private FBProject As Project = Nothing                      ' FileBound Project object
    Private cmd As String = ""                                  ' SQL query string
    Private FBFile As FileBound.File = Nothing                  ' Filebound file holder
    Private FBRoutes As RouteCollection = Nothing               ' FileBound route collection holder


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ' Set SqlDataSource connection string
        FBSqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FB_0371tcc").ConnectionString

        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            ' Set values to variables
            Page_setup() ' Here I set values to variabels
            setRoute_debug("Admin1 Test")

        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Sub sendEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles sendEmail.Click
        ' CAN I HAZ SOME TEST????
        'setRoute_debug(emailTo.SelectedValue.ToString)

        Response.Write("<script>" & Me.FBRoutes.TotalCount.ToString & "</script>")

    End Sub

    Private Sub setRoute_debug(ByVal route_to As String)

        ' IF WE HAZ SOME ITEMS FINISH THEM MUHUHAHHAHAHA
        If FBBusiness.LoggedInUser.RoutedItems.TotalCount > 0 Then
            For Each item As RoutedItem In FBBusiness.LoggedInUser.RoutedItems
                item.Complete("Completed!")
            Next
        End If




        ' DEBUG MODE #YOLO
        ' I'VE DONE IT I CAN HAZ ROUTEZ
        For Each r As Route In Me.FBRoutes
            If r.Name = route_to Then
                For Each doc As FileBound.Document In FBFile.Documents
                    doc.Route(r.ID)
                Next

            End If
        Next


    End Sub

    Private Sub Page_setup()
    ' Some code that sets values
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click the button it throws this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Line 46:         Response.Write("<script>" & Me.FBRoutes.TotalCount.ToString & "</script>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button click on as asp.net page would come as a `PostBack`.

Your are setting up the page only in

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack
```

This is fine for asp.net controls, cause they retain their state across PostBacks using the `ViewState`.

When click a button, server receives a new request, and a new object of Page is created. Your variables are not set for this object.

Set your page level variables on every PostBack, like this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Set SqlDataSource connection string
    FBSqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FB_0371tcc").ConnectionString

    Page_setup() ' Here I set values to variables

    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        'Set Page level control values like TextBox values
    End If
End Sub
```